# posting to openGraph ALWAYS returns with the same ID

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am developing an iOS application that needs to post openGraph actions on objects.
I am using **[the facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)** to test my openGraph objects and actions.
The process always results with the same `id`, meaning that even if I change parameters in my URL like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/MyNamespace:MyAction?MyObject=http://mysite.com/facebook/og1.php?page=1
```

**or**

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/MyNamespace:MyAction?MyObject=http://mysite.com/facebook/og1.php?page=100
```

please note the URL **`page` parameter change**

and yet I get a post on facebook with the expected results, but always the same ID, meaning I can post only once per user instead of being able to post many opengraph actions.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the ID actually **changes**. The ID is a fair number of digits, and increments each time by around 10,000 or so. 
So only one digit or two in the middle would change. Made me think it was the very same ID.